# have problem scrapy comment on website: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I encounter json decode error and don't know why there the new url I get is not the expected one but the login website.

I try to scrape comments from a Chinese website (weibo). I have found the basic framework of that web through Chrome tools for web developer. It is a json-form file and has a clear structure.

```py
import requests
import re
import codecs
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

url2 = "https://m.weibo.cn/comments/hotflow?id=4384234225528313&mid=4384234225528313&max_id=138836201356688&max_id_type=0"
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
    }


def get_page(max_id, id_type):
        params = {
                'max_id': max_id,
                'max_id_type': id_type
                }

        try:
                r = requests.get(url2, params=params, headers=headers)
                rr = r.url
                print(rr)
                rrr = requests.get(rr)
                if rrr.status_code == 200:
                        return rrr.json()

        except requests.ConnectionError as e:
                print('error',e.args)


def parse_page(maxid):
        if maxid:
                items = maxid['data']
                item_max_id = {}
                item_max_id['max_id'] = items['max_id']
                item_max_id['max_id_type'] = items['max_id_type']
                return item_max_id

m_id = 0
id_type = 0

for a in range(1,30):

        maxid = get_page(m_id, id_type) #maxid=rrr.json()
        results = parse_page(maxid)
        time.sleep(2)
        m_id = results['max_id']
        id_type = results['max_id_type']

        for i in range(len(maxid['data']['data'])):
                data = maxid['data']['data'][i]['text']
                with codecs.open(r'/Users/apple/Desktop/suicide.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as ff:

                        hanzi = ''.join(re.findall('[\u4e00-\u9fa5]',data)) 
                       ff.write(hanzi+'\n'*2)
```

[weblink1](https://m.weibo.cn/comments/hotflow?id=4384234225528313&mid=4384234225528313&max_id=138836201356688&max_id_type=0&max_id=0&max_id_type=0)

[weblink2](https://passport.weibo.cn/signin/welcome?entry=mweibo&r=https%3A%2F%2Fm.weibo.cn%2Fcomments%2Fhotflow%3Fid%3D4384234225528313%26mid%3D4384234225528313%26max_id%3D138836201356688%26max_id_type%3D0%26max_id%3D138836201356688%26max_id_type%3D0)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise JSONDecodeError(Expecting value, s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Above is the results I get. I can get the comments on first page, but then it shows I cannot continue.
Another issue is that there should be a new url which has similar structure as the original one so that I can scrape comments of second page, but I only get the login url.

Comment: what is the value of a when it fails?

Comment: Can you provide the original url (and any required inputs) where you used dev tools to get the above. Looks like providing a bad url is leading to 302 redirect

Comment: The weblinks above are the original urls. But it may need to login... It is a json form file which contains the whole info in that weisite. I don't know how to show you the screenshot, so I just paste some text(as follows) I got after I open it...                                      ok 1
data 
data 
0 {…}
1 
created_at "Tue Jun 18 09:18:00 +0800 2019"
id "4384462072253292"
rootid "4384462072253292"
rootidstr "4384462072253292"
floor_number 38
text "<a href='/n/Theo-Z'>@Theo-Z</a>"
disable_reply 0